# displaying data inside listview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using listbox to display list of data, I tried with this

```
foreach (MyData a in data)
{     
    var row = new ListViewItem();
    row.Text = a.Name;
    row.SubItems.Add(a.Code);
    row.SubItems.Add(a.Name2);    
    listView1.Items.Add(row);
}
```

This way I'm getting data displayed inside columns and I need to display inside row, also subitems Code and Name2 are not displayed.

What I'm doing wrong here

Comment: The question title and body says ListBox. The code says ListView. Which is it?

Comment: sorry, listview .. changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see subitems you need to use `Details` mode of `ListView`. Also make sure you have added three columns to listview (you can do it in designer):

```
listView.Columns.Add("Name");
listView.Columns.Add("Code");
listView.Columns.Add("Name2");
listView.View = View.Details;
// ... your code
```